# Keeping an ofstream object open even after the function exits

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a code written in c++ in visual studio, which basically writes a set of floating point numbers ( 70 floating points )to a binary file on each tick of a timer.The numbers are acquired from a machine which an experiment is done.

```
WriteToFile( float* buffer, int buffersize )   
    {
     ofstream out;
     out.open( filename,ios::app)
     for(int i =0;i< buffersize ;i++)     // buffersize is 70 here
             {  
               out.precision(6);
               out.setf(ios::fixed,ios::floatfield);
               out.write( (const char*) &buffer[i], sizeof(float));
             }
    }
```

This function is called for each tick of a timer.This is taking so much of time, even after the experiment is done i have to wait the program to acquire the data and save it to the file.The reason for its slowing down is, for every tick it need to open the binary file and have to find the location where it previously stopped.If there is a way i can keep the file open all the time and the place location pointer in the same location where it stopped previously i might be able to speed it up.Does any body have any suggestions on it ?
Basically how to keep and ofstream open, even after the function exits ?

Comment: Try having the ofstream variable and the location pointer as global variables, and only open the file once before the function is called?

Comment: i can put the ofstream variable as global, but how to keep the file opened  when the function is called once  ?

Comment: there is the is_open() function, here is reference: [ofstream::is_open](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/is_open/). You can check if it is already open, and open it if it has not been opened yet.

Comment: Your output function seems strange; `precision` and `setf` affect formatted output (i.e. writing text), but you're only calling `write()` (i.e. unformatted output, writing binary data). If you want the file as binary, you should open it with `std::ios::binary`, drop the formatting calls and you can just output the whole buffer at once.

Comment: Just make a global stream - filename is already a global

Answer (score 3):

The C++ way would be to encapsulate the timer function and the stream object into a class, something like this:

```
class BufferWriter
{
  std::ofstream out;

public:
  explicit BufferWriter(const std::string& filename)
    : out(filename.c_str(), std::ios::app)
  {
    out.precision(6);
    out.setf(std::ios::fixed, std::ios::floatfield);
  }

  void writeToFile(float *buffer, std::size_t bufferSize)
  {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bufferSize; ++i) {
      out.write((const char*)(buffer + i), sizeof(float));
    }
  }
};
```

Simply create an instance of this somewhere, and call its `writeToFile()` function in each timer tick. When the instance is destroyed, the file will be closed. You can also `flush()` it at the end of each `writeToFile()` if you want.

To elaborate on the use case, you could do it for example like this:

```
int main()
{
  BufferWriter buf("MyBufferFile.dat");
  Timer t = createTimer();
  t.setTickCallback(buf, &BufferWriter::writeToFile);  // call buf.writeToFile() on each tick
  t.start();
  waitUntilFinished(t);
}
```

The important point is for the `BufferWriter` instance to exist as long as the entire timer-using operation runs. As long as the `BufferWriter` instance exists, its `out` member will exist as well and the corresponding file will remain open.

Comment: That doesnt seems to work, i want to keep the ofstream.out open even after the scope of ofstream is over. defining something like the whole  ofstream.out as static ?

Comment: @sarath There must be a misunderstanding somewhere; the `out` member in my answer will exist as long as the `BufferWriter` instance exists, and its lifetime is fully under your control. I've expanded the answer to include a simplified use case (to demonstrate object lifetimes), can you check it out and see if you've been using it the same way?